# Assign n-dimensional Array to an object

Tags: java, arrays, biginteger

I have written code in Java to find the largest array of BigIntegers the JVM can support.

It starts by adding creating a BigInteger[] and redeclaring it with larger sizes. Once the size is equal to Integer.MAX_VALUE, it starts creating a BigInteger[Integer.MAX_VALUE][] and begins to increment the 2nd dimenstion. Once the OutOfMemory Exception is thrown, it stops, and returns the last array successfully initialized.

Unfortunately, based on the RAM of the computer, it could be a BigInteger[], BigInteger[][], all the way up to a BigInteger[][][][][]. How would I assign that to a private object? array? in my class, so I can refer to it later?

For instance:

```
    BigInteger[] x;
    x = new BigInteger[][] //error, dims dont match.
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think this has much to do with the computer. supporting multi-dimension arrays isn't so tasking.

Comment: @eylashiv It is when each BigInteger contains an int[], all the memory of which is allocated. Moreover, my try catch statement used to throw the out of memory error quite often.

Comment: With the clarification edit, I now understand ... thinking.

Comment: Side note: The type `BigInteger` is irrelevant to your experiment. You might as well use `Object` arrays. All object references have the same size, regardless of type.

Comment: The result of this experiment will only indicate how much heap space has been allocated to the JVM. It won't tell you anything about the hardware.

Comment: True, then I need to find how big of an array the JVM can hold then. Updating original question to reflect such.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're asking for unbounded limits, I would suggest using a `LinkedList<BigInteger[]>`. Or, you could go with `LinkedList<ArrayList<BigInteger>>` and just use `List`s all the way.

Because it's a classic doubly linked list not backed by an array, it doesn't have the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` limit on the number of elements it can contain. It's only constrained by available memory. This makes it so effectively you're only dealing with two dimensions.

Once you hit `BigInteger[Integer.MAX_VALUE]` in an array size (or `ArrayList`), you add it to the `LinkedList` and continue.

The only caveat is that `size()` won't work once you're over `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements, only a traversal of the entire list will tell you that. This is easily overcome if you want by extending `LinkedList` / creating your own proxy class and keeping your own count as a `long`

**Edit to add:** I still may be completely misunderstanding your question or what you're trying to achieve. If your trying to figure out the number of array dimensions the JVM will support ... it's 255 as defined in the [JVM spec section 4.3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.2)

If you're trying to figure out how many reference values you can create / hold in memory, then `BigInteger` really doesn't enter in to the picture; `Object[10]` is going to be exactly the same size as `BigInteger[10]` from the standpoint of the array itself; it's an array that can hold 10 reference values. Reference values are a fixed size just like a pointer in C; you could simply create a `LinkedList<Object>` and start filling it with `null` - when you run out of memory, that's how many you can create. There is the overhead of each node in the List, of course. In which case, my original answer might be better.

If you're trying to figure out how many instances of `BigInteger` you can create ... then again, just create a `LinkedList<BigInterger>` and have at it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this question needs clarification, but to answer your question, all objects in Java are inherited from the `Object` class, thus a variable of type `Object` can reference anything.

```
Object obj = new BigInteger[1];
Object obj = new BigInteger[1][1];
Object obj = new BigInteger[1][1][1];
.
.
.
```